# PYTHON TypeError: validTicTacToe() missing 1 required positional argument: 'board'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, self, tic-tac-toe

I am new to python and trying to run this code on VScode. It gives an error saying **TypeError: validTicTacToe() missing 1 required positional argument: 'board'**. What am I doing wrong here?
I am actually trying to understand how does the **self** works. I know **c++** so if you can explain in comparison to c++ it would be of great help.

Also, this is a leetcode problem, it works good on leetcode, but looks like I have to make some changes before running it on VScode.
TIA

````
def validTicTacToe(self, board) -> bool:
    X, O = self.countSymbols(board)
    if O > X:
        # Os can't  be greater than Xs
        return False
    elif abs(X-O) > 1:
        # Difference can only be 1
        return False
    elif X > O:
        # X can't have more moves than O if O is already won
        if self.checkTriads(board, 'O'): return False
    else:
        # X and O can't have equal moves if X is winning
        if self.checkTriads(board, 'X'): return False
    return True


def countSymbols(self, board):
    X = 0
    O = 0
    for row in board:
        for i in row:
            if i == 'X':
                X+=1
            elif i == 'O':
                O+=1
    return X,O
                    
def checkTriads(self, board, sym='X'):
    # Checking for Hight triads
    i = 0
    while i<3:
        if (board[0][i] == board[1][i] == board[2][i] == sym):
            return True
        i+=1
            
    # Checking for width
    i=0
    while i<3:
        if (board[i][0] == board[i][1] == board[i][2] == sym):
            return True
        i+=1
            
    # Checking for diag.
    if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] == sym):
            return True
    if (board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0] == sym):
            return True
    return False

board=["O  ","   ","   "]
validTicTacToe(board)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined your functions in the manner of object methods. These will always automatically receive their instance object as the first parameter. By convention, this parameter is named `self`. You however didn't declare a class to contain these methods. You can either remove the `self` parameters from your functions or wrap them inside a class definition:

```py
class TicTacToe():
    def validTicTacToe(self, board) -> bool:
        # ...

game = TicTacToe()
board = ["O  ", "   ", "   "]
game.validTicTacToe(board)
```

To make actual use of the class mechanism, the board should be a property:

```py
class TicTacToe():
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.board = board

    def validTicTacToe(self) -> bool:
        # now you can use self.board instead of passing it around

board = ["O  ", "   ", "   "]
game = TicTacToe(board)
game.validTicTacToe()
```